# Single sign on not working on Java migration 1.7

Tags: java, single-sign-on, openam

I am using openAm 9.5.4 as service provider and salesforce as IDP. With existing java 1.6 version of OpenAm my IDP initiated sso works. 
But when we migrate java version of openAm to 1.7 sso failes with error "HTTP Status 500 - Single Sign On failed.". What may be the issue causing by change of java version ?

One more important question that I want to confirm is, whether OpenAm 9.5.4 even supports SSO on Java 1.7? Someone tried this combination?

Comment: OpenJDK, or Oracle? You get 500 from your service? If so - please provide exception, that is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

OpenAM 9.5.4 [only runs on Java 1.6](https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/OpenAM+9.5.4+Release+Notes). The first OpenAM release that supported Java 1.7 was 11.0.0, see the [release notes](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/11/release-notes/#java-requirements).